# FTPWebRequest Can't Get GetRequestStream

Tags: c#

Thanks for view my question.
I'm using FTPWebRequest to upload file,but it's not working.
Here my code.

```
ftp.KeepAlive = false;
ftp.UsePassive = true;

ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
ftp.UseBinary = true;
ftp.ContentLength = fileInf.Length;
int buffLength = 2048;
byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];
int contentLen;
FileStream fs = fileInf.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
Stream strm = ftp.GetRequestStream(); <--- Can't get request stream.
contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
error = null;
```

Here is Network Trace

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [7928] Associating FtpWebRequest#58093648 with FtpControlStream#60452428
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7928] Socket#30630844::Receive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7928] Data from Socket#30630844::Receive
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7928] 00000000 : 32 32 30 20 46 54 50 56-69 74 61 20 53 65 72 76 : 220 FTPVita Serv
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7928] 00000010 : 65 72 20 72 65 61 64 79-2E 0A                   : er ready..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7928] Exiting Socket#30630844::Receive()   -> Int32#26
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7928] Socket#30630844::Receive()
```

Then throw an timeout error.

FTP Server sent 220 welcome message,but can't get Stream.

I tried set UseBinary to FALSE,but still not working..

any idea???

thanks

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "Can't get request stream"? You've shown a network trace, but you haven't told us what the result is. Does it hang? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: Sorry for that.. it's hang on there.then throw an UNKNOW ERROR..

Comment: try set usepassive to false, it might also be a firewall issue

Comment: I guess the problem is protocol end with \n , Windows need \r\n..

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you can log in to the server but not GetRequestStream returns null, it is a permissions issue on the server for the credential you are using